# no python unit tests discovered in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have seen some other issues around this topic but nothing that would provide a solution to my problem.

I try to run python unit tests (using unittest package) from VSC version 1.40.2 on Linuxx64.

I am able to run those tests with pytest from command line and all of them are positive so there is no syntax issues. I also see 0 problems on the bottom bar in VSC.

I try to run test which are in file test_myfile.py, as you can imagine I would like to test a file called myfile.py which is in the same workspace as test_myfile.py.

When I run all test with VSC the output looks like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

settings.json

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**.pyc": true
    },
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
}
```

I am new to VSC and read some tutorials on testing in VSC, but maybe I am missing something.
Could you suggest some settings to check which might cause this behavior?

Comment: Do the tests run successfully from the terminal when you do it manually? You can look in the Output Panel for the command the extension runs on your behalf to see if it works there but not in the extension.

Comment: I have a little update. I enabled pytest and disabled unittest. I use pytest as a unittest runner and did not think about it previously. Now it works just fine. I am sorry for the confusion and really thankful for your help.